# Can't understand this line of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Thanks for your attention and time.

I'm modifying an existing JavaScript but can't understand a line of code. Please help me understanding this line:

```
 rowArray[i].value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[sortOn].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

I am clear till `.getElementsByTagName('td')`, `sortOn` is being passed in this function as a parameter. But I couldn't understand `[sortOn].firstChild.nodeValue;`

Please guide me,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')` will get all `td` elements that are children of `rows[i]`. The `[sortOn]` part selects the `td` whose index is specified by the `sortOn` parameter. The `.firstChild.nodeValue` gets the text contained in the first element within that `td`.

**Update:** In the DOM, elements such as `<td>` can only contain other child elements, but they don't have any text property. The text itself is contained in a special "text node" that is a child of the `<td>` node. This is why you use `.firstChild` to obtain the text node, then use `.nodeValue` to get the text contained in that node.

Comment: thanks casablanca,

it is helpful. Can you pleaes a little more explain .firstChild and .nodeValue seprately. I am confused when sortOn will spacify the cell than what will for .firstChild.nodeValue ?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

`.getElementsByTagName('td')` - returns a list of TD elements.
`.getElementsByTagName('td')[sortOn]` - fetches a single element from that list
`.firstChild` - returns the first element that is positioned inside this TD.
`.nodeValue:` see here - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue

Comment: thanks AndreyKo,

It is helpful.

I am confused in one thing. When [sortOn] will move us to required td. 
But .firstChild I cant understnad it. please help a little more.

thanks

Comment: please just explain 
.firstChild - returns the first element that is positioned inside this TD.

In my td there will be test. That is why I am confused why it is being used. Is there any way that I can avoid it and directly accessing text. If it has some advantage please guide me.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

[sortOn]
is array notation. It works in exactly the same way as rows[i]. Let's say sortOn is equal to 5, and that there are seven elements in rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td'), which is an array of `<td>` elements. Then you will get the sixth one (JavaScript arrays are 0 based), and this will be a `<td>` element.

firstChild means the first element beneath that td, so in this case

```
<td><em>emphasis</em><strong>some text</strong></td>
```

the `<em>` element is the first child

nodeValue is in this case the contents of that element, so "emphasis" will be returned.

You may well find the [gecko DOM reference useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference)

Answer (score 1):

`getelementsByTagName` returns you an array of element with same tag, then by using `sortOn` variable you select specified one form collection and take his first child and look on it.